# Creating a Shift pattern on an existing date table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to input a shift pattern to my sql date table.
We currently have a shift identifier A/B/C/D that work on a 2 day 2 night 4 off 12 hour shift pattern. Here is my table TimeShift_Dim

| ShiftDate | ShiftId | DayDesc | DayKey | DayNight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-02 07:00:00.000 | C | Wednesday | 4 | Day |
| 2023-08-02 19:00:00.000 | B | Wednesday | 4 | Night |
| 2023-08-03 07:00:00.000 | A | Thursday | 5 | Day |
| 2023-08-03 19:00:00.000 | C | Thursday | 5 | Night |
| 2023-08-04 07:00:00.000 | A | Friday | 6 | Day |
| 2023-08-04 19:00:00.000 | C | Friday | 6 | Night |
| 2023-08-05 07:00:00.000 | D | Saturday | 7 | Day |
| 2023-08-05 19:00:00.000 | A | Saturday | 7 | Night |

I want to create a new column TeamID that consists of shifts A / B / C only, that never work saturday nights or sundays. They follow the below table so that this week A will be on week 1, B on week 2 and C on week 3. Then next week C=1, A=2, B=3 etc
[image: new shift pattern]

How would i go about adding this column both going forwards and historically according to the above shift pattern. As of monday 31st July, A = week 1 / B = week 2 / C = week 3

Comment: FYI, there is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76812431/edit) feature; you should not delete and repost questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH Shifts AS (
SELECT * 
  FROM (VALUES 
        (1, 0, 'Monday',    'Days'  ),  (2, 2, 'Monday',    'Days'  ),  (3, 1, 'Monday',    'Days'  ),
        (1, 0, 'Tuesday',   'Days'  ),  (2, 2, 'Tuesday',   'Days'  ),  (3, 1, 'Tuesday',   'Days'  ),
        (1, 0, 'Thursday',  'Nights'),  (2, 2, 'Thursday',  'Nights'),  (3, 1, 'Thursday',  'Nights'),
        (1, 0, 'Friday',    'Nights'),  (2, 2, 'Friday',    'Nights'),  (3, 1, 'Friday',    'Nights'),
        (1, 1, 'Thursday',  'Days'  ),  (2, 0, 'Thursday',  'Days'  ),  (3, 2, 'Thursday',  'Days'  ),
        (1, 1, 'Friday',    'Days'  ),  (2, 0, 'Friday',    'Days'  ),  (3, 2, 'Friday',    'Days'  ),
        (1, 1, 'Saturday',  'Nights'),  (2, 0, 'Saturday',  'Nights'),  (3, 2, 'Saturday',  'Nights'),
        (1, 2, 'Monday',    'Nights'),  (2, 1, 'Monday',    'Nights'),  (3, 0, 'Monday',    'Nights'),
        (1, 2, 'Tuesday',   'Nights'),  (2, 1, 'Tuesday',   'Nights'),  (3, 0, 'Tuesday',   'Nights'),
        (1, 2, 'Friday',    'Days'  ),  (2, 1, 'Friday',    'Days'  ),  (3, 0, 'Friday',    'Days'  ),
        (1, 2, 'Saturday',  'Days'  ),  (2, 1, 'Saturday',  'Days'  ),  (3, 0, 'Saturday',  'Days'  )) a(TeamID, ModWeek,WeekDay,ShiftDesc)
)

SELECT c.date, c.DayName, s1.ShiftDesc AS Team1, s2.ShiftDesc AS Team2, s3.ShiftDesc AS Team3
  FROM Calendar(1,1) c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Shifts s1
      ON c.WeekNumber % 3 = s1.ModWeek
      AND c.DayName = s1.WeekDay
      AND s1.TeamID = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Shifts s2
      ON c.WeekNumber % 3 = s2.ModWeek
      AND c.DayName = s2.WeekDay
      AND s2.TeamID = 2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Shifts s3
      ON c.WeekNumber % 3 = s3.ModWeek
      AND c.DayName = s3.WeekDay
      AND s3.TeamID = 3
 WHERE c.Date BETWEEN '2023-08-01' AND '2023-08-31';
```

Since you have a 3 week rotation, we can apply the `MODULO` operator to the week number and determine which team is on which rotation for any given week.
In this example I've joined it to a `Calendar` table TVF.

| Date | DayName | Team1 | Team2 | Team3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-01 | Tuesday |  | Nights | Days |
| 2023-08-02 | Wednesday |  |  |  |
| 2023-08-03 | Thursday | Days |  | Nights |
| 2023-08-04 | Friday | Days | Days | Nights |
| 2023-08-05 | Saturday | Nights | Days |  |
| 2023-08-06 | Sunday |  |  |  |
| 2023-08-07 | Monday | Nights | Days |  |
| 2023-08-08 | Tuesday | Nights | Days |  |
| 2023-08-09 | Wednesday |  |  |  |
| 2023-08-10 | Thursday |  | Nights | Days |
| 2023-08-11 | Friday | Days | Nights | Days |
| 2023-08-12 | Saturday | Days |  | Nights |
| 2023-08-13 | Sunday |  |  |  |
| 2023-08-14 | Monday | Days |  | Nights |

Comment: Hi, This looks like exactly what I am after apart from a couple of things that I need some clarification on:
Saturday nights are not worked and Wednesdays are included in the shift pattern so every day and night mon-fri then sat day - how would i go about modifying your matrix in the cte to reflect this

Then i am assuming i can just pivot the table so that I can have it laid out as follows
|Date|Dayname|DayNight|TeamID|

Thanks this is a great answer

Comment: The `VALUES` contain all the data in the following format:
`TeamID`, `ModWeek`, `Weekday`, `ShiftDesc`
To add a day for team 1/ModWeek 0 you'd just add a row describing the shift you want: `(1, 0, 'Wednesday', 'Days')` for team one, on mod week 0 (the first week of the rotation), Wednesday, day shift.